# My command for minecraft executing a command at an entity won't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to make a pokeball system and I'm testing it on a chicken named TestCatch. I want the command to test if there is an item named pokeball near the chicken. I have this command:

```
 execute @e[name=TestCatch] ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"Pokeball"}}}}
```

Whenever I use it it just says

> [16:18:51] Failed to execute 'testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"Pokeball"}}}}' as TestCatch

How can I fix this?

Comment: The command is structurally correct. Ensure the command block is running correctly and that there is an item that can be found with `/testfor`.

Comment: The command appears to be correct, so the command output means that the target of the testfor was not found. The only thing I can think of is that you're throwing the item like a snowball (default is right-click) rather than dropping the item (default key Q). Thrown snowballs are not the same as dropped snowball items.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the radius:

```
execute @e[name=TestCatch] ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[type=Item,r=5] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"Pokeball"}}}}
```

this will test if there is a `Pokeball` item within 5 blocks of `TestCatch`

Comment: This would cause a false positive, not a false negative.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer would be:

`execute @e[name=TestCatch] ~ ~ ~ /testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"Pokeball"}}}}`

You just missed one `/` before `testfor`.

Comment: /execute commands do not need a slash in front of them